# How to regenerate Stellar Archives?

Tags: stellar-core

We are running a private stellar network and we are seeing missing archives files. Can the network regenerate the archive files? New nodes are not able to synch because of this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the archives are the canonical source of history, and at least one full non-corrupt copy must be preserved if a network is to function properly.

Archives cannot be restored from any other source, including the databases on nodes, which only store the current (most-recent) ledger state. Archives are the primary copy.